# How to convert between JvmTarget and JavaVersion?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jvm

Within my project I need to assign the JVM version as different types:

- `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget`
- [`org.gradle.api.JavaVersion`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api/-java-version/index.html)

In order to keep the project maintainable I like to define the JVM version in a **single place**. Hence, I would like to either (1) **convert** between the different types or (2) to create both a `JvmTarget` instance and a `JavaVersion` instance **from an integer**.

## Pseudo code (1)

```kotlin
JvmTarget.fromInteger(11) // JvmTarget.JVM_11
JavaVersion.fromInteger(11) // JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

In the `JvmTarget` class `fromTarget(String)` already exists.

## Pseudo code (2)

```kotlin
JvmTarget.ofJavaVersion(JavaVersion.VERSION_11) // JvmTarget.JVM_11
JavaVersion.ofJvmTarget(JvmTarget.JVM_11) // JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as having [`JvmTarget.fromTarget()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/e1df52bc0255d24651141f5a2094d3ab7e61d4d2/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-compiler-types/src/generated/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/dsl/JvmTarget.kt#L13) which accepts a string, we have [`JavaVersion.toVersion()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/JavaVersion.html) which accepts a Java `Object`, which can be either an integer or a string<sup>1</sup>.

So to define both from an integer you can do:

```
val javaVersionSetting = 21
val jvmTarget = JvmTarget.fromTarget(javaVersionSetting.toString())
val javaVersion = JavaVersion.toVersion(javaVersionSetting)
```

Or from a string, which doesn't involve any conversion of basic types:

```
val javaVersionSetting = "21"
val jvmTarget = JvmTarget.fromTarget(javaVersionSetting)
val javaVersion = JavaVersion.toVersion(javaVersionSetting)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>And if you want three for a party someday, there is also [`JavaLanguageVersion.of()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/toolchain/JavaLanguageVersion.html) from Gradle's [Java toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html) which has overloads accepting an integer or a string.